# Jquery file validator : How to call a function on success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am using jquery file validator plugin.
Here is the link : 
http://adamsanderson.github.io/jQuery-File-Validator/#documentation
I can call a function *before validation* and *onInvalid* input.
But can someone tell me how can i call a function if file is a **valid input**?
Here is the code..

```
$( el ).fileValidator({
    onValidation: function(files){ /* Called once before validating files */ },
    onInvalid:    function(validationType, file){ /* Called once for each invalid file */ },
    maxSize:      '2m', //optional
    type:         'image' //optional
});
```

Comment: Here is **your** code? You just copy pasted the code from the site, of course you might need to make some adjustments.

Comment: @blex I am sorry but i dont know how to create plugins. If some one knows that maybe he can just add one more method 'onValid' just opposite of 'onInvalid' inside the plugin.
whole Plugin is hardly few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a few changes need to be done to the plugin, I will not go into details as theses changes are spread in the entire file, but here is the version you need:

```
/**

Uploading files, only to find that they are too large, or the wrong type is frustrating.
The `fileValidator` plugin lets you warn users before they start uploading 
enormous files.

Usage
-----

Simply select the file inputs you wish to validate, and pass in a callbacks to handle invalid files.

    $( el ).fileValidator({
      onValidation: function(files){ ... },
      onInvalid:    function(validationType, file){ ... },
      maxSize:      '2m', //optional
      type:         'image' //optional
    });



*/
(function($){

  validFile = true;

  $.fileValidator = function(options){
    var validations = [];
    var onInvalid = options.onInvalid;
    var onValid = options.onValid;


    for (var key in $.fileValidator.validations){
      if (!options[key]){ continue; }
      validations.push( $.fileValidator.validations[key](options[key], onInvalid, onValid));
    }


    return function(file){
      for(var i=0, len = validations.length; i < len; i++){
        validations[i].call(this, file);
      }
      if(validFile){onValid.call();}
    };
  };

  $.fileValidator.validations = {
    maxSize: function(maxSize, invalid, valid){
      if( typeof maxSize == 'string' ){ 
        maxSize = $.fileValidator.sizeToBytes(maxSize);
      }

      return function(file){
        if (file.size > maxSize){ invalid.call(this,'maxSize',file); validFile = false; }
      };
    },

    type: function(contentType, invalid, valid){
      var isValid;
      if( typeof contentType == 'function' ){ 
        isValid = contentType; 
      } else if (contentType.constructor === RegExp ) { 
        isValid = function(type){ return type.match(contentType); }; 
      } else { 
        isValid = function(type){ return ~type.indexOf(contentType); }; 
      }

      return function(file){
        if (!isValid(file.type)) { invalid.call(this,'type', file); validFile = false; }
      };
    }
  };

  $.fn.fileValidator = function(userOptions) {
        var options = $.extend({
          // Validations
          maxSize: null,
          type: null,

          // Callbacks
          onValidation: $.fileValidator.doNothing,
          onInvalid: $.fileValidator.doNothing,
      onValid: $.fileValidator.doNothing
        }, userOptions);

        return this.each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            var validator = $.fileValidator( $.extend({}, options, el.data()) );

          el.bind('change', function(event){
            var files = this.files || [];
            options.onValidation.call(this, files);
            for(var i=0, len=files.length; i < len; i++){
              validator.call(this, files[i]);
            }
          });
        });     
    };

  $.fileValidator.doNothing   = function doNothing(){};
  $.fileValidator.sizeToBytes = function sizeToBytes(size){
    var scale = 1;

    if (~ size.indexOf('k')){ 
      scale = 1024; 
    } else if (~ size.indexOf('m')){ 
      scale = 1024 * 1024; 
    } else if (~ size.indexOf('g')){ 
      scale = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; 
    }
    return parseInt(size,10) * scale;
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Use it like this:

```
$(function(){  
    $('input').fileValidator({
        onValidation :  function(){ validFile=true; },
        onInvalid:      function(type, file){ alert('Error: '+type); },
        onValid :       function(){ alert('Yay!'); },
        type:        'image',
        maxSize:      '1m'
    });
});
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

#### Edit

The `validFile` variable is true from the beginning, and if it meets an error, it becomes false.

Comment: Thanx for trying but Not working for me :(
http://jsfiddle.net/z8y2s/1/
See this.
Using alert for both of them it dont work.

Comment: Ok, not working at the moment, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Nice brain u used but i think 'Type' Still not working..
When u select a diff file type it shows it Valid instead of error!!
Size working fine!

Comment: @jackkorbin OK, Now it's working :D Check the JS Fiddle.

Comment: I see you figured it out in version 21 ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you're just validating them by extension, create your own simple js method. for example:

```
<!-- File input in form -->
<input id="myId" class="button" name="myFile" type="file" onchange="getName()" >

<script>
    function getName() {
        var filename = document.getElementById("myId").value;
    alert(filename.split('.').pop());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Watif the user has disabled extensions? Only the file name?
2. plugin also check the size of File.
3. Watif the user renamed some txt file to jpg?

Comment: Well, if you continue to use the file validator, can't you just add a function call in the onValidation? Or just add the code you need to that section?

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know how to make a plugin or how it is made.. But I think looking at the code.. any novice can change it because it is very few lines of code.