# Pass 'This' jquery selector manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

```
<input type='file' class="img-input" id="add-img-1" onchange="show_img(this);" />
```

How can we pass 'this' selector of a file input manually to a function?

Like this :

```
$('input.img-input').fileValidator({
        onValid :     function(){ show_img( $(this) ); },
        type:        'image',
        maxSize:      '1m'
});
```

This is not working thou, I tried passing id of input also.. but no luck.
Can anyone help me?

HERE is the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z8y2s/16/

Comment: If you are using [this plugin](http://adamsanderson.github.io/jQuery-File-Validator/#documentation), there's no `onValid` event.

Comment: I edited the plugin and made a onValid event.
Have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315080/jquery-file-validator-how-to-call-a-function-on-success

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8y2s/18/

Comment: check my answer below. Also, you should use `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: Thanx its working :)
Can u please also tell me how to clear the input if the file selected is wrong??
http://jsfiddle.net/z8y2s/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass this inside `call` function, so that your `valid` callback can use it.

```
(function($){

  validFile = true;

  $.fileValidator = function(options){
    var validations = [];
    var onInvalid = options.onInvalid;
    var onValid = options.onValid;


    for (var key in $.fileValidator.validations){
      if (!options[key]){ continue; }
      validations.push( $.fileValidator.validations[key](options[key], onInvalid, onValid));
    }


    return function(file){
      for(var i=0, len = validations.length; i < len; i++){
        validations[i].call(this, file);
      }
      if(validFile){onValid.call(this);}
    };
  };

  $.fileValidator.validations = {
    maxSize: function(maxSize, invalid, valid){
      if( typeof maxSize == 'string' ){ 
        maxSize = $.fileValidator.sizeToBytes(maxSize);
      }

      return function(file){
        if (file.size > maxSize){ invalid.call(this,'maxSize',file); validFile = false; }
      };
    },

    type: function(contentType, invalid, valid){
      var isValid;
      if( typeof contentType == 'function' ){ 
        isValid = contentType; 
      } else if (contentType.constructor === RegExp ) { 
        isValid = function(type){ return type.match(contentType); }; 
      } else { 
        isValid = function(type){ return ~type.indexOf(contentType); }; 
      }

      return function(file){
        if (!isValid(file.type)) { invalid.call(this,'type', file); validFile = false; }
      };
    }
  };

  $.fn.fileValidator = function(userOptions) {
        var options = $.extend({
          // Validations
          maxSize: null,
          type: null,

          // Callbacks
          onValidation: $.fileValidator.doNothing,
          onInvalid: $.fileValidator.doNothing,
      onValid: $.fileValidator.doNothing
        }, userOptions);

        return this.each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            var validator = $.fileValidator( $.extend({}, options, el.data()) );

          el.bind('change', function(event){
            var files = this.files || [];
            options.onValidation.call(this, files);
            for(var i=0, len=files.length; i < len; i++){
              validator.call(this, files[i]);
            }
          });
        });     
    };

  $.fileValidator.doNothing   = function doNothing(){};
  $.fileValidator.sizeToBytes = function sizeToBytes(size){
    var scale = 1;

    if (~ size.indexOf('k')){ 
      scale = 1024; 
    } else if (~ size.indexOf('m')){ 
      scale = 1024 * 1024; 
    } else if (~ size.indexOf('g')){ 
      scale = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; 
    }
    return parseInt(size,10) * scale;
  };
})( jQuery );
```

See, I passed `this` when calling `onValid` (Line no 21)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z8y2s/17/)

Comment: The one line of code u edit worked like a charm!!
Thanx a lot indian :D
I wonder how it clicked u?

Comment: Can u please also tell me how to clear the input if the file selected is wrong??
http://jsfiddle.net/z8y2s/19/

Comment: `this` is not jQuery object. It does not have `val` method. You can use `$(this).val('');`. Here's the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z8y2s/20/)

Comment: Thanxx again sir :) Just one last question how can i detect if some one uploaded the file after chnging extension to jpg because the type method only checks the extension? I need the validation on client side only.

Comment: I have never used file api, but I am sure that won't be possible on client site. You should always use server side validation for your security. Client side validation is just to ease user's input and decrease server load.

Comment: I did the server side already but i wanted client side also..
select images in the Twitter when u post a tweet.. It validates in client side only!!

Comment: Or we can use ajax to perform client side validation using server!!

Comment: I don't know how twitter does that. May be they are using ajax. A quick google shows this link [Determine filetype using javascript](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/determine-an-images-type-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=1KF7Uvd0xN6)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a parameter inside function like this:

```
function(el){ show_img( $(el) );
```

Whole code:

```
$('input.img-input').fileValidator({
        onValid :     function(el){ show_img( $(el) ); },
        type:        'image',
        maxSize:      '1m'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input.img-input').fileValidator({
   onInvalid:    function(type, file){ show_img(file); },
   maxSize:      '1m'
});
```

Comment: I have to call that function on "onValid"
And theres no parameter for it.